# Post-Install of Cocoapod get main project directly

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

In creating a CocoaPod Podspec for a `vendored_framework` I need to install a shell script to be run after all other `build_phases` in the main project. The only way I have found to do this is by groping the directory for the `.xcodeproj` file from the `Podfile`.

```
post_install do |installer|
  project_name = Dir.glob("*.xcodeproj").first
  project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_name)
  project.targets.each do |target|
    inject_shell_script_build_phase(target)
  end
  project.save
end
```

This seems ridiculous given that `pod install` or `pod update` is running and clearly has this information already. Is there a way to get the `project` reference directly without having to glob or hardcode the project filename?

Comment: Might you share the magic in `inject_shell_script_build_phase`??

Comment: you can use **prepare_command** in .podspec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html

There is `installer.pods_project`

```
post_install do |installer|
  project = installer.pods_project

  project.targets.each do |target|
    inject_shell_script_build_phase(target)
  end

  project.save
end
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods/Pod/Installer#pods_project-instance_method
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods/Pod/Project inherits from https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/xcodeproj/Xcodeproj/Project

---

to iterate the *.xcodeproj you can do

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    user_project = target.user_project

    puts "#{user_project.path}"
  end
end
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods/Pod%2FInstaller%3Aaggregate_targets
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods/Pod/AggregateTarget

Comment: This only gives you Pods targets not the main project.

Comment: I'll check it out in a few minutes, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick... Notice the `post_integrate` hook. Otherwise my changes got overridden (ignored?) unless I did it via the direct file open.

```
post_integrate do |installer|
  project =  installer.aggregate_targets[0].user_project
  project.targets.each do |target|
    inject_shell_script_build_phase(target)
  end
  project.save
end
```